# codeigniter sql query complex construction

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following request

```
SELECT `categories`.*, `categories`.`parent_id` AS `join_parent_id`, (SELECT name FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id = 2 LIMIT 1) AS name, (SELECT slug FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id = 2 LIMIT 1) AS slug, (SELECT name FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id != 2 LIMIT 1) AS second_name, (SELECT slug FROM categories_lang WHERE category_id = join_parent_id) AS parent_slug, (SELECT id FROM categories AS sub_categories WHERE sub_categories.parent_id = categories.id LIMIT 1) AS has_subcategory FROM `categories` WHERE `slug` = 'linge-textile-vintage' AND `visibility` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

When executing, I have error "Unknown column 'slug' in 'where clause'"

the slug field is in the category_lang table but it is defined with this statement in the sql query

```
(SELECT slug FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id = 2 LIMIT 1) AS slug
```

Thank you for helping

Here is the php code which create this request :

```
public function build_query($lang_id, $all_columns = false)
{
    if ($all_columns == true) {
        $this->db->select('categories.*, categories.parent_id AS join_parent_id');
    } else {
        $this->db->select('categories.id, categories.parent_id, categories.parent_tree, categories.category_order, categories.featured_order, categories.storage, categories.image, categories.show_image_on_navigation, categories.parent_id AS join_parent_id');
    }
    $this->db->select('(SELECT name FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id = ' . clean_number($lang_id) . ' LIMIT 1) AS name');
    $this->db->select('(SELECT slug FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id = ' . clean_number($lang_id) . ' LIMIT 1) AS slug');
    
    if (item_count($this->languages) > 1) {
        $this->db->select('(SELECT name FROM categories_lang WHERE categories_lang.category_id = categories.id AND categories_lang.lang_id != ' . clean_number($lang_id) . ' LIMIT 1) AS second_name');
    }
    $this->db->select('(SELECT slug FROM categories_lang WHERE category_id = join_parent_id) AS parent_slug');
    $this->db->select('(SELECT id FROM categories AS sub_categories WHERE sub_categories.parent_id = categories.id LIMIT 1) AS has_subcategory');
}

//get category by slug
public function get_category_by_slug($slug)
{
    $this->build_query($this->selected_lang->id, true);
    $this->db->where('slug', clean_str($slug))->limit(1);
    $this->db->where('visibility', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('categories');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: please have a look at UNION: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: Why you are using so many sub queries, use just joins and it will be easy for you to get data. do you have slug column in you categories table?